# xampp php not importing css, images, but imports php files

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to copy a website to my local machine. I have downloaded all the code, and things like page redirection, and importing work fine. But displaying images, css, and using javascript doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    include ($root . '/resources/config.php');
    echo "$imagepath/user_suit.png";
?>
<div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
        <div id="loginLink" class="menu"  onmousedown="return false;" >
            <img src="
            <?php
            echo $imagepath
            ?>/user_suit.png" width="15" height="14" alt="Member Login"> Member Login
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; Welcome Guest!
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#loginLink").click(function(){
        // load contact form onclick
        $("#contentPane").hide();
        $("#loadingPageGif").show();
        $("#contentPane").load("
            <?php
            echo $server
            ?>/code/login/Studentlogin.php", 
            function() {    
                $("#loadingPageGif").hide();
                $("#contentPane").fadeIn();
            });
    });
</script>
```

In this code, the embedded image does not load, and clicking on the link does nothing.

I can right click on the unloaded image, go to view image, and it correctly displays.

I can put echo lines in $root . '/resources/config.php' and they show up correctly.

The site I downloaded it from does not have these issues, so I am guessing it has something to do with xampp.

Comment: I have a really stupid question, but just covering bases. Are the images actually in a folder? If so, print your html, what url does the image have? And if you put that url in your browser, does that image show?

Comment: Yes, the images are in a folder. at the top I have the line echo "$imagepath/user_suit.png"; copying what that echo's into the url bar leads to the correct image.

Comment: Get in your web form source and print this piece for me: <div id="loginLink" class="menu"  onmousedown="return false;" >
            <img src="
            <?php
            echo $imagepath
            ?>/user_suit.png" width="15" height="14" alt="Member Login"> Member Login
        </div> That should print the actual link to the image. If it does not your doing something wrong.

Comment: And I'm guessing this space doesn't help either: <img src="
            <?php

Comment: It displays an image box, with an unloaded image. I can right click and view image, and it redirects to the image correctly.

removing the space <img src=" <?php to <img src="<?php doesn't change anything

Comment: it redirects to localhost/bla/bla/bla/image.[jpg,png,whatever]? or to online (like www.something)

Comment: you should really print the source of that piece of code.

Comment: <div id="loginLink" class="menu"  onmousedown="return false;" >
    <img src="localhost:82/public_html/images/user_suit.png" width="15" height="14" alt="Member Login"> Member Login
   </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser adds `http://`, you should make that

```
<div id="loginLink" class="menu" onmousedown="return false;" > <img src="http://localhost:82/public_html/images/user_suit.png" width="15" height="14" alt="Member Login"> Member Login </div>
```